# Yii render partial for menu header - different menu content for different modules

Tags: php, yii

I want to separate the header code into /layouts/_header.php and footer into /layouts/_footer.php and render them in my modules :

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('//layouts/_header'); ?>
```

I'm having a problem because my universal header has a subheader and some modules are having different subheader content.

_header.php

```
<style type="text/css">

    .header__fnav .navbar-brand{
    background:#fff;
    }

    .header__fnav .navbar-brand .st0{
        fill:#00AAC6;
    }
    .header__fnav .navbar-brand .st1{
        fill:#CE3640;
    }
    .header__fnav .navbar-brand .st2{
        fill:#F3A629;
    }
    .header__fnav .navbar-brand .st3{
        fill:#6EA945;
    }
    .header__fnav .navbar-brand .st4{
        fill:#E75C2D;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px)
    {
        .uni-header .header__fnav .navbar-brand {
            height: 40px;
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 20px;
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 35px;
            padding: 12px 0;
            width: 42px;
            margin-left: 0!important;
        }
    }
    .header__fnav .navbar-brand svg {
        height: 15px !important;
        width: 18px !important;

    }
</style>


<header class="header">
    <div class="uni-header">
        <nav class="navbar header__fnav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1">
            <div class="container container_dark">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right">
                    <button type="button" class="toggle-menu menu-right navbar-toggle">
                    <span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="logo_main hidden-xs hidden-sm" href="https://mymagic.my/">
                        <img width="119" height="20" src="https://mymagic.my/wp-content/themes/magic2017/assets/art/logo.svg" alt="MaGIC">
                        <span class="header__tagline hidden-xs hidden-sm">Malaysian Global Innovation &amp; Creativity Centre</span>
                    </a>
                    <?php $this->renderBreadcrumb(true) ?>
                    <div class="box_white">
                        <form class="search_block" action="https://mymagic.my/">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" href="#">
                                    <i class="icon-search"></i>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" value="" name="s">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="dropdown-menu" aria-label="Close"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
                                        <button type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <ul class="nav_pillars">

                            //This is the subheader part 


                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav_main hidden-md hidden-lg">
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://mymagic.my/about/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">About</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://mymagic.my/programs/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Programs</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://mymagic.my/events/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Events</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://mymagic.my/facilities/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Co-Working</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a target="_blank" href="http://resource.mymagic.my/#sthash.ETSyAo9e.dpbs" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Resources</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="https://mymagic.my/ace/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">ACE</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://mymagic.my/news/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">News</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://mymagic.my/publications/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Publications</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav_secondary hidden-md hidden-lg">
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://mymagic.my/jobs/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Jobs</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://mymagic.my/contact/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Contact Us</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav_main nav_myacc hidden-md hidden-lg">
                        <li><a href="http://connect.mymagic.my/"><i class="icon-key"></i> My Account</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

How can I render this in my modules and fill in the subheader part for each module?

So say for my x module - I have these subheader options - I'm not sure how to render partial the header and have these subheader menu in it.

```
        <ul class="nav_pillars">

            <li role="presentation" class="<?php if($this->activeMenuMain=="start"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/index') ?>">Get Started</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="<?php if($this->activeMenuMain=="explore"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/explore') ?>">Explore</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="<?php if($this->activeMenuMain=="about"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/about') ?>">About</a></li>
            <?php if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest): ?>
            <li role="presentation" class="<?php if($this->activeMenuMain=="manage"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/manageOrganizations') ?>">Manage</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="dropdown hidden <?php if($this->activeMenuMain=="manage"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Manage <i class="icon-down-open-big"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="<?php if($this->activeMenuSub=="manageOrganizations"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/manageOrganizations') ?>">Organisations</a>
                    <li class="<?php if($this->activeMenuSub=="managePartners"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/managePartners') ?>">Partners (deprecated)</a></li>
                    <li class="<?php if($this->activeMenuSub=="manageEnterprises"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/manageEnterprises') ?>">Enterprises (deprecated)</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//cpanel') ?>"><?php echo Yii::app()->name ?></a></li>                           
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="<?php if($this->activeMenuMain=="logout"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//site/logout', array('returnUrl'=>$this->createAbsoluteUrl('/idea'))) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->user->username ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
                <img src="<?php echo ImageHelper::thumb(100, 100, $this->user->profile->image_avatar) ?>" class="img-circle" style="width:24px; height:24px" /> Logout
            </a></li>
            <?php else: ?>
            <li role="presentation" class="<?php if($this->activeMenuMain=="login"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//site/login', array('returnUrl'=>$this->createAbsoluteUrl('/idea'))) ?>">Login</a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: You can create two different header and use it

Comment: That won't be productive - I have a lot of modules

Comment: this is not the conventional approach that you have used, you should have created a `MenuHelper` that should return the Menu items array that could be used inside the `Nav`,`Menu` or `SideMenu` widget provided by Yii2 and then populate your menu accordingly you can even decide on the base of the current `controller` , `module` or `action` which menu to be visible and which not. Look into [**`yii\bootstrap\Nav`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.2/yii-bootstrap-nav)